# RPi with openELEC - hebrew subtitles are seen as jibberish

Tags: kodi, openelec, subtitles, xbmc-subtitles

got openELEC 4.2.1 on my RPi b+ to serve as an HTPC.
when I tried to use xbmc's subtitles downloader, it finds the correct subtitles file for the video, but hebrew subtitles are not being encoded right.
where and how can I configure the encoding?